# How to modify my code to include geolocation of each tweet and let machine run the code continuously with a 15min rest time?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, geocoding, tweepy

How do i edit the code below to include coordinates and place full_name from each tweet into the csv file? And to let the code run by itself using while loop with a 15 min break time as Twitter API has a rate limit of 180 requests per 15 min?

```
#Get the name of the spreadsheet to write to.
fname = '_'.join(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtag_phrase))

#Open spreadsheet to write data to.
with open('%s.csv'%(fname),'w') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file)

    #write header row to spreadsheet.
    w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])

    #for each tweet matching our hashtags, write relevant info to the spreadsheet
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag_phrase, \
                               lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(500):
        w.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), [e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']], tweet.user.followers_count])
```